# Size UILabel in UIPickerView to fit

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uipickerview

I want to make the text size in the `pickerView` to become smaller if the text does not fit in the label. For example, whenever the text shows like this "This is a test for somebo..." I want it to automatically size itself to a smaller size so it should fit. Here is the code I'm using:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *lView = (UILabel *)view;

    if (!tView) {
        tView = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [tView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
        tView.numberOfLines = [categorie count];
    }
    tView.text = [categorie objectAtIndex:row];
    return tView;
}
```

I tried to set the number of lines to 0 but that didn't solve my issue. I then tried to make the label `sizeToFit`, and that didn't work either.

I also tried making the label's frame height, taller, so it would be multiple lines, with didn't help either.

What did I get wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the docs for `UILabel`. You want to do the following:

```
if (!tView) {
    tView = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [tView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
    tView.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    tView.minimumScaleFactor = 0.7; // adjust as needed
}
```

Do not set `numberOfLines`. That's only useful when you want the text to wrap to multiple lines.

Comment: How would I make it multiple lines instead of making the font smaller?

Comment: @MikeSteevson That's a whole other question. Start by looking at the questions to the right under the "Related" section. Several seem to cover that topic.